# Making 2 or 3 INTs unique? Is hashing the way to go?

Tags: mysql, hash

The background is that from 2 or 3 unsigned integers I want something unique. I've done cantor pairs but they grow out of an `BIGINT UNSIGNED` when using 3.

Now I'm into hashing, first I went with `MD5` and `char(32)` but know I'm into `CRC32` with `INT UNSIGNED` since it's numeric, therefore fast. The goal is high performance reading from this index.

Is hashing the only way? Can I maintain a reasonable collision probability for ~200,000 rows?

Comment: How big is the field you will store the unique in? Are the integers randomly distributed?

Comment: @Ariel The base data is 2 or 3 UNSIGNED INTs and that can go into any available MySQL field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `binary(12)` (12 bytes) which can uniquely store three 4 byte integers.

Or `decimal(30)` which also can do that and doesn't require you to first convert the integers to a binary encoding (just 0 pad them to 10 digits and append them together, MySql will do the conversion for you).

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood of an unintentional MD5 collision is 1.47×10<sup>-29</sup>. You reasonably assume safety with 200k rows. MD5/SHA1 are designed for speed, so fast shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Not the hashing, but the reading from MySQL, I will clarify that.

Comment: That really shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: It makes a huge difference! MD5 is 16 bytes, which is more than you need to just store the 3 integers in the first place!

Comment: Even if you're being bizarre and fetching a million rows all at once, that's still only 16MB.

Comment: Sure, but what would be the point of doing that? It makes as much sense as storing random bytes in my tables that does nothing and is used for nothing. And unless you binary encode the md5 character string it actually would take 32 bytes to store.

Comment: I will do `GROUP BY` and `IN(...)` statements so there will be a lot of overhead if this is not kept to a minimal.

Comment: Indexing'll cover that issue. Either way's going to work, I'm just saying there's no real reason to rewrite to avoid MD5 for these reasons if someone has already coded it that way.

Answer (score 0):

How well does MySQL handle compound keys/indexes?

If MySQL can handle them in a performant way then one option would be to simply store your three integers in three separate `INT` columns and have a compound key that spans all three columns.